# How do I reformat MSBUILD xml in Resharper or VS Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

Both ReSharper 6 and VS 2010 treat my MSBUILD files as XML when it has the .Proj extension, but it will not allow me to reformat the text.  The options are greyed out in ReSharper and VS 2010. How do I turn it on?  Right now, I am forced to either copy and paste the code into a file with an xml extension reformat and copy and paste it back, or rename the file with an xml extension.

Comment: Open the file in notepad++ (with XML plugins installed), select language as XML and reformat.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [Visual Studio macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that will do all the renaming and reformatting for you. Macros can be bound to the toolbar and to commands (keyboard shortcuts), so you can make this into a single click/shortcut.

Comment: I am not familiar with VS Macros and it's been tough enough getting my head around MSBUILD.  I was hoping for an option I could just tick and get it working.

Comment: @JoelRodgers - Nothing _that_ easy, though you _can_ [run an external tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9814d200.aspx). If you can script the actions into a batch file (or powershell script), this may be an easier option for you.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains answer as of today (2013-12-02) is that project files are excluded from code cleanup. There's a discussion of the issue on their [code cleanup page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Running_Code_Cleanup.html) which contains a link to a bug named [Verify that Code Cleanup works with MSBuild .proj files](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-316642) which contains the information that the fix version is only **9.0**!

So there seems no way short of an external tool to get this done.